# Northern Ireland electoral wards shapefile

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

Anyone have any idea where to get a shapefile for NI wards that corresponds to the 2011 census?

NISRA has a small area shapefile that is supposed to be aggregable up to ward boundaries, but the file has a self-intersection in it that keeps breaking.

As a general poll, how do people feel about the availability of geospatial data in NI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a shapefule for 2001 boundaries that's still valid for the 2011 census data I'm working with.

[UK Data Service](http://borders.edina.ac.uk/html/boundary.html) has the file, but you'll need to register with them. (As a non-profit media group, it was easy enough for us to do so. For-profit may be more difficult.)

Also, be aware the ward boundaries were changed in 2012, so they'll be different for data dated thereafter. UKDS doesn't have that shpfile, and I believe the only source so far is Land & Property Service and the Ordinance Survey of Northern Ireland.

They have a map service you can use in Arc or QGIS, but of course is heavily restricted. Otherwise there's a lot of money involved.

Answer (score 4):

If you go [to the NISRA website](http://www.nisra.gov.uk/geography/home.htm) then you'll get all shapefiles in both .shp and .tab formats for 2011 census as well as some other geogrpahies.

Be awere of the copyright.

Comment: Oh and to add to your poll - i think its spot on (internally in the public sector). If youre on the outside yes it can be tough yet [INSPIRE](http://www.gistrategyni.gov.uk/index/news-archive/agi_ni_conference.htm) will change all that.